# uwsgi: RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, worker

I am running uwsgi (with django in a docker container), and every worker that spawns comes with this error:

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
web_1          | spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 18, cores: 2)
web_1          | Exception ignored in: <function _after_at_fork_child_reinit_locks at 0x7fd944954ca0>
web_1          | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 260, in _after_at_fork_child_reinit_locks
web_1          | spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 19, cores: 2)
web_1          |     _releaseLock()  # Acquired by os.register_at_fork(before=.
web_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 228, in _releaseLock
web_1          |     _lock.release()
web_1          | RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock
```

Here is my uwsgi **.ini** file:

```
[uwsgi]
strict          = true          ; only explicitly understood configration allowed
module          = myapp.wsgi
need-app        = true          ; don't start if can't find or load django app

### PROCESS SETTINGS ###############

master          = true          ; gracefully re-spawn and pre-fork workers, consolidate logs, etc
enable-threads  = true

processes       = 10             ; maximum number of worker processes
threads         = 2
thunder-lock    = true

socket          = 0.0.0.0:8000  ; too complicated for me to get a unix socket to work with docker, this is fine.
#socket          = /tmp/myapp.sock

vacuum          = true          ; on exit, clean up any temporary files or UNIX sockets it created, such as HTTP sockets, pidfiles, or admin FIFOs
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term     = true

### WORKER MANAGEMENT ##########
max-requests    = 1000          ; Restart workers after this many requests
max-worker-lifetime = 3600      ; Restart workers after this many seconds
reload-on-rss   = 2048          ; Restart workers after this much resident memory
worker-reload-mercy = 60        ; How long to wait before forcefully killing workers

harakiri        = 60            ; Forcefully kill workers after 60 seconds
py-call-osafterfork = true      ; Allow workers to receive signals such as signal.alarm

### LOGGING ####################

disable-logging = true          ; Disable built-in logging
log-4xx         = true          ; but log 4xx's anyway
log-5xx         = true          ; and 5xx's
#log-to          = /var/log/uwsgi.uwsgi.log
```

How can I fix this?  Am I missing a package?

my Docker files uses `python:3.8-slim` but the same thing happens in `3.7-slim`

**Dockerfile** packages added:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils 2>&1

# Install git, process tools, lsb-release (common in install instructions for CLIs)
RUN apt-get install -y git procps lsb-release

# Required for psycopg2: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/699
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev

# Install any missing dependencies for enhanced language service
RUN apt-get install -y libicu[0-9][0-9]

# Install uwsgi
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `py-call-osafterfork` uwsgi config option.

Source: [uwsgi github issue](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1978).

Answer (score 12):

If you are using PyCharm, the issue might be solved by enabling Gevent compatibility. You can do this by navigating to `Settings/Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger` and then ticking the checkbox `Gevent compatible`.

Comment: Lifesaver, not sure why this does not came up before in my searches. Let's see if this will help to come up first _sys.settrace(None)